# Is it possible for a human not to select the most rewarding option?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, free-will

It seems that out of all the options available, humans are wired to always make the ideal (satisfying/rewarding) subjective choice, and not go with the second best option or some other.

When a person has a list of options to go with, ordered by preference, if he/she would go for what seems to him/her as the second best or other option, that specific choice would actually be the -real- #1 option, because the criteria, that made him go for #2 are more important then those which sorted his options initially.

Generally, going on a vacation (#1), is perceived as a better choice then going to work (#2). Unless, finishing a project results in extra money, or a sense of accomplishment, which would subjectively make the latter choice a real number one. And so, if staying at work would then be perceived as more important/rewarding/satisfying, would that person go on a vacation after all? And if they did, would that mean, that vacationing was the real #1 priority?

So is it possible to settle for a second or later best choice, if we have the options in correct order, based on the most important criteria?

Comment: Just a comment... many people (e.g., in arguing against altruism) tend to argue that we always pick our #1 preference.  I have a problem with the unfalsifiability of such a thing (one can _always_ say what one does is #1; one could even define it this way, but IMO that makes the rank meaningless).  Perhaps a better way to look at this is to look at a negotiation (e.g., where to eat with a loved one); in such cases it's hard to argue that you're going with your own #1 preference (one could argue *negotiating* is the choice, but there's the problem of why you go *there*).

Comment: @HWalters I think I see your point. When choosing the restaurant for yourself, your #1 choice would naturally be your #1 favourite restaurant. But on hers/his birthday the criteria shift so that number one choice simply isn't your #1 restaurant as usual, but his/hers . Your objective here is to make your loved one happy, and so you will choose a place, that meets it best. But not second best.

Different factors, such as opening hours or prices, may come into play. This would shift your criteria and a different place would then be perceived as best, but again, would you be able to go with #2?

Comment: I take it you don't have kids :)

Comment: @Richard Very funny. I take it you do have kids, but you haven't yet noticed that what seems to be best for them, is actually #1 choice for your own DNA to propagate ;)

Comment: @Marko36 well thats all very dawkins, but i know the decisions i make are not the best for me personally, but for them. Some other human beings.

Comment: @Richard Dawkins would be happy, but so would you, personally. Wouldn't it be your top choice for other humans, your kids, to benefit, inspite of what you are sacrificing? You could stay home watch football, but you'd go to the zoo, because good parenting is more satisfactory, then the game (for you and people like yourself, I guess).

Comment: @Marko36 not really. Many people choose to leave their families and resume a life lived solely for their own pleasure. I don't enjoy standing by a cold soccer pitch watching my kids play badly. I don't enjoy cleaning up sick at 3AM. I do it in spite of myself, because I love my children. I take your point, but sacrifice of any kind is intellectual not visceral.And long term sacrifice, knowing you'll probably be put in a retirement home as a reward, is difficult to reconcile with your premise. It requires a particular kind of honour code

Comment: @Richard, this is now more of a chat (which is nice, but unappropriate in the comment section), and I would probably repeat myself anyway, so let me just add that, again, you do all the things you dislike, and bring many other sacrifices, so you can go ahead with your number one choice - your kids. Soccer isn't a thing you'd give up, but I bet others are. And as for retirement homes, it may be a thing many people don't realize, or don't know how to tackle. So they go with "We all die alone anyway", or "Even your own wife is a stranger, after all".

Comment: @Marko36 the worst part of sacrifice is that it is complete. No thanks from the children, no thanks from your partner, no thanks from society (I'm middle aged and white, my sacrifices are worthless), and not even any cold intellectual comfort, because dawkns says so. This.. in microcosm is the sickness of the modern world. Honour and sacrifice are worthless.

Comment: @Marko36 it's not conversation, it's argument. I believe you.are wrong. I'm attempting to provide you with an epiphany of sorts.

Comment: The problem with this question, and most of the answers, is that it assumes that the set of choices is well ordered.  In real life, it isn't.  If we could objectively evaluate each choice and score it from 1 to 100, making the final choice would be easy.  But real choices can't be scored that way.  In most real-life situations, there are several choices, not only two, and in most cases the choices compare the way rock/paper/scissors compares:  there is no best choice.

Answer (score 2):

There's a complicated issue that arises in the concept of "ordered by preference."

On one hand, one may define this phrase such that what you describe is tautological.  This is the argument used by the phrasing "Well you must have really wanted X all along."  This phrasing is indeed useful for developing formulae approximating one's preference.

The other is that we define a priority order for options before the choice is made, and then a human exerts "free will" to decide between them.  In this case, the devil is in the details.  Given some unbounded amount of decision making time, we like to believe that humans will pick their first preference.   This is at the root of why we model humans as "rational actors."  They try to maximize some internal goal.

However, in practice, humans do not have unbounded time.  The time one spends thinking affects the outcome, as the world keeps moving.  As such, humans rarely follow this simple rule precisely.  Consider the example of police officers who make a split second decision as to whether to shoot someone or not.  It is highly unlikely that they will make a decision based on the objective truth of the entire scenario because they have not had time to analyze everything.  The Trolley Problem is an excellent way to explore this: there's always *some* nuance that you haven't considered which could matter when you find yourself holding the controls of a runaway trolley.

If we try to mix these two, we see that a rational human must fundamentally be aware that, in the moment, they will make a decision based on incomplete information.  Given enough time, humans will try to optimize their lives to "win" at this decision.  But at this point it gets sufficiently murky that it's hard to keep going with the model of a simple ordered priority list.  The long standing philosophies surrounding death show that we've got some really complicated thoughts regarding what our most important decision might be.

So, as such, I would say that if one uses the tautological pattern for priority, then we always follow it.  However, if one takes one step off of this extreme, towards the idea of having a pre-determined ordered priority list, humans begin to do things which are not modeled well with this priority list.

Comment: Furtermore, if one takes the tautological view that "most rewarding" means "the one chosen", then it is not something we are wired for, as the question puts it, it just is so by definition...  WRT rational choice, I do not think it is just a matter of insufficient time or information, as individuals are quite capable of holding contradictory opinions, desires and ethical views.

Comment: @sdenham As a skeptic, I feel that if an individual wishes to act rationally, thus resolving conflicting opinions, they can dig into the language and definitions behind their rational thought until they are murky enough to permit a resolution of the conflict.  This may, of course, be on the time scale of science fiction with people who live "forever" (such as The Doctor from Dr. Who), so practically I would have to agree with you that we can hold contradictory opinions that cannot be resolved even if there is a desire to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Humans are capable to make their choices subject to an algorithm, such as a coin toss. If you are willing to follow the coin toss, then if the coin toss decides for the second best, humans can choose second best, fully aware of what they would have chosen without the coin toss.

Socially this is important as an example for group cohesion, where group members will follow the decisions of a leader (or a democratic majority) over their own preferences.

Answer (score 0):

1. Economists and rational choice theorists recognise the phenomenon of 'satisficing' where we do not go for the best (by relevant criteria), but for what is good enough or merely acceptable or satisfactory rather than the best possible or optimal  - or in your terms 'the most rewarding option' (again relevant criteria).
2. There's also the point that we can be mistaken, objectively or just by our own standards, about what is 'the most rewarding option'. We can't 'choose the most rewarding option' if we are ignorant of or mistaken about what that object is.

Answer (score -1):

If one assumes that human choices are the result of an optimization algorithm as one would find running in an automated logic machine where what is "most rewarding" is optimized, one would expect the machine and the human to make the same choices.

However, such machines run on completely formal, "explicit knowledge" rather than "[tacit knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_knowledge)".  Further if one assumes that for a human being (not a machine) inference is rooted in that human's tacit knowledge, as Michael Polanyi suggests, then there may be a discrepancy between what a machine optimizes and what a human chooses.

Here is the question:

> So is it possible to settle for a second or later best choice, if we have the options in correct order, based on the most important criteria?

There may be no correct order based on the most important criteria for the human to choose from resulting in the human making a choice based upon tacit rather than explicit knowledge, or, in other words, on non-verbalizable concepts rather than formal concepts. That human may then settle for what another human might consider to be not the best choice.

---

Polanyi, M. (1966). The logic of tacit inference. Philosophy, 41(155), 1-18.

Comment: I think I see your point. (And thank you for the edit, btw.) But is it important, whether the knowledge is explicit or tacit? It would actually be the latter, and so - yes a "best" choice is diiferent for different people. But the point is, if a person has a subjective number one choice (I believe so, regardless of the process / knoledge it made it a number one), can he go ahead with the second?

Comment: @Marko36 If one is going to have a "correct" order then one would need explicit knowledge. A machine should be able to validate the order and best choice if it is possible to create the ordering. Tacit knowledge allows the human to alter that order and choose something the machine would not. In order to go ahead with the second option, the human has to have an ordering. We assume we have this ordering because we assume we are making rational choices, but our choices may not be rational in the sense of reasoning from propositions of external knowledge.